# CoffeeScript Preserve Multiple `this` objects?

Tags: node.js, express, sqlite, coffeescript

I'm in a rather unique situation (one I've never found myself in before) and I can't find anything on how it should be handled, so I thought I'd ask here. (and perhaps start a good discussion on how it should be handled)

I'm writing a Node.js/Express application that does a series of database calls in various route handlers. I'm using the [node-sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) module to make the database calls. In this case the user is uploading a file, so I take that from the form POST data and save it to the filesystem (will be moved to blob storage later) and generate some xml files for other reasons. The way that I name these files is by the id in the database to facilitate routes like '/file/:id' to GET the file later on, as well as leveraging the database to ensure I don't have name collision issues.

I'm doing this in CoffeeScript so I'm wrapping this model in a `class`, so it uses `this` (or `@`) to access these helper methods. Before I was doing a `last_insert_rowid()` call to get the id of the thing I just inserted but this opens me up to potential race conditions. So as it turns out when you do an `INSERT` in the node-sqlite3 module the callback it calls when it's done saves the last inserted row id in the `this` object (so `(err) -> fileid = @.lastID`). Now for some code (names changed and simplified).

```
uploadFile: (fileData, cb) ->
  @.openConnectionIfClosed()
  @db.serialize =>
    # preserve the @ object to allow calls to class methods like @.saveFile
    @db.run 'insert into thing (val=$val)', $val: 'some_val', (err) ->
      if err
        cb err
        return

      # @ refers to the this object provided by @db.run
      fileid = @.lastID

      async.waterfall [
        (async_cb) =>
          # uh oh, the @ object is the one from the db library, not my class
          # earning me a 'method undefined' error
          @.saveFile fileid, async_cb 
        # etc... you get the idea
        ...
      ], (err) -> cb err
  @.closeConnection()
```

So I'm needing to retain the class `this` object to access instance methods, but I also need to get the `lastID` value out of the `this` object returned by default from the callback in the db call. Obviously if I change the callback on the db call to fat arrows I can access my class methods, but then the `@.lastID` returns `undefined`.

What's the "proper" way to achieve this? (in CoffeeScript or JavaScript, doesn't particularly matter) I think that the way I can solve this is by assigning a context variable like `ctxt = @` at the top of the method but obviously this isn't favorable. Any ideas?

EDIT: Oh, and I forgot to mention, I can't just name the file something else because I also need that id to update the database. The call to `async.waterfall` does: Save file -> generate xml metadata file & save it -> add the path of the xml file to the database entry retroactively. Though I could potentially use a statement to do that without completely isolated database calls, haven't investigated that yet.

Comment: I'd love to help with some Javascript, like it says in the title.

Comment: You can use either, it applies equally well as all the `=>` in CoffeeScript is doing is calling the function and calling `call` or `apply` (can't remember which) at the end and passing `this`. Though good point. Changed it!

Comment: Also, sidebar, assigning `this` to a context variable does work, but again not favorable if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: does the db.run function allow you to pass a context to the method call?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The `this` inside the callback of the run method is actually a SQLite Statement object. Can't pass anything. I'm just wanting to know, in general, what patterns exist for keeping track of contexts like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, if you need to preserve a particular context, its standard practice to use the variable self, as such:

```
var self = this;
```

In CoffeeScript, the fat arrow is standard practice for cases like this, though using 'self' is not wrong either.

Comment: Interesting. That's essentially what I did (only used `ctxt` instead of `self`). Thought there might be a different way. In this case I can't use the fat arrow as I needed the two different contexts in the same closure. Thanks!